# Boolean dynamic memory allocation cannot be delete

Tags: c++

```
include <iostream>        
int main()
{
    bool a=new bool;
    delete a; 
    return 0;
}
```

I try to delete the boolean malloc, but so far it keeps giving me the error that bool type expression cant be deleted

Comment: Note that there is pretty much never a need to write `new bool` in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform `delete` on `bool`, you should `delete` the pointer instead.

```
bool* a=new bool;
delete a;
```

In your code, `a` is a variable with type `bool`, it's initialized from the pointer created by `new bool`, which could convert to `bool` implicitly; `false` for null pointer, `true` for non-null pointer.

Comment: dang it I forgot to put the *, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

- `new bool` returns a boolean pointer (`bool *ptr`), therefore you
  can't atribute `new bool` to `a`, which is a bool date type.
- And also, one can only `delete` pointers

So you must declare `a` as a boolean pointer: `bool *a = new bool`